# Error while running service stop in BASH

Tags: bash

Hi all I am trying to start the apache server loging into it using this .

ssh ra001@apcahesserver "cd /user/main;sudo su -c 'cd /maint/config;service httpd stop'"

but i am getting an error saying 
bash: service: command not found

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: how do i resolve this error 
bash: service: command not found
do i need to pass the command [Service httpd start] in ""

Comment: There are so many security issues with what you are trying to do, but essentially the PATH is set to prevent you from doing this by accident.   You could try to call service by the full path but you may run into other problems, and you should reconsider how you are remote-managing services and maybe use one of the many frameworks that exists -- anyway this question is not about programming, but system and server administration so you should ask the question on one of the other affiiated sites instead

Comment: see if httpd exists in /etc/init.d/ or try the newer command:  systemctl status httpd